# jquery ToggleSlide any of 2 div-children inside of div-parent (which are repeated)

Tags: jquery, html

I have:

```
<div class="papa-div">
    <div class="child-a">
          <!-- content of deal-header -->
    </div>
    <div class="child-b">
          <!-- content of deal-body -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="papa-div">
    <div class="child-a">
          <!-- content of deal-header -->
    </div>
    <div class="child-b">
          <!-- content of deal-body -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Number of blocks is random with each page reload.

**Goal:**

When I press any of `.child-a` or `.child-b`, it gets opened if was closed, or closed if was opened. `.child-a` and `.child-b` of one `.papa-div` may be either (1) both opened, or (2) only one of them opened, or (3) both closed.

However, once I click `.child-a` or `.child-b` of any other instance of `.papa-div`, I want ALL currently opened `.child-a` and `.child-b` of all other `.papa-div` blocks get closed, but any of `.child-a` or `.child-b` (inside the new `.papa-div`) that was clicked should get opened.

In other words, I want accordion effect, but considering that each accordion block has 2 "sub-blocks" (i.e. "child-a" and "child-b"), that can each be opened/closed independently of each other.

Currently I have 2 similar jquery click()'s for each of `.child-a` and `.child-b`, like:

```
$('.child-a').click(function(e) {
  p = $(this).parents('.papa-div');
  ch = deal.find('.child-a');
  ch.addClass("opened");
  closeDivs(p, ch);
});
```

And each of these blocks causes `function closeDivs(p,ch) {...}`.

Inside the function I check several times if `p.hasClass("opened")`, which is a lot of manual actions written in the code for a quite simple thing. Any ideas how to make it short and simple? Thanks

Comment: You could set a flag to the parent and close the children whose parent doesnt have the flag

Comment: could you post the whole code (html + js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding an extra class (e.g. `selected` ) to the papa div, you can remove all opened instances of its children, regardless of its type (child-a or child-b)

```
$('.papa-div > div').click(function(e) {
    $('.papa-div.selected') 
  .not( $(this).toggleClass('opened').parent().addClass('selected'))
  .removeClass('selected').children().removeClass('opened');
});
```

What the above does :
`$('.papa-div.selected')...removeClass('selected').children().removeClass('opened')` removes `selected` from the currently selected papa-div and all `opened` classes from its children.

`.not(...)` skips the current papa div: `$(this).toggleClass('opened').parent().addClass('selected')` toggles the clicked div and selects its parent in one go. Because the end of the chain returns the selected parent, it can be used directly in the `not()`

Example:

```js
$('.papa-div > div').click(function(e) {
 $('.papa-div.selected')
  .not( $(this).toggleClass('opened').parent().addClass('selected'))
  .removeClass('selected').children().removeClass('opened');
});
```

```css
.papa-div > div{  
  width:50px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:yellow;  
  border:1px solid black;
}

.papa-div > .opened{
  background-color:blue;
  height:50px;
}

.selected{
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="papa-div">
    <div class="child-a">
          <!-- content of deal-header -->
    </div>
    <div class="child-b">
          <!-- content of deal-body -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="papa-div">
    <div class="child-a">
          <!-- content of deal-header -->
    </div>
    <div class="child-b">
          <!-- content of deal-body -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I finally solved it somehow differently, but as this answer also efficiently solves it and has such a great supporting snippet, will mark it as correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('.papa-div').removeClass('flagged');
$('.child-a').parent().addClass('flagged');
$('.papa-div:not(.flagged) .child-a, .papa-div:not(.flagged) .child-b').removeClass('opened');
$(this).toggleClass('opened');
```

Here, first I remove class `flagged` from every parent div.

Then I add back the `flagged` class to the parent div of the child I'm clicking.

Then I remove the class `opened` from every other child div that doesn't belong to the parent of the clicked child.

And finally i toggle the `opened` class to the current clicked child